# Why some badges can't be chosen as the "next badge"?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

I can't find some badges e.g. *unsung hero* or *famous question* for the *next badge* option. Why?

The screenshot pictures an empty search result for the *unsung hero* badge:
[image: Why "unsung hero" can't be chosen as the "next badge"]